# What is the Path API for kubectl top pods

Tags: kubernetes, top, kubectl, rancher

I use this command "kubectl top pods" using Kubectl command

I need path api for this command

I need return data from this command  "kubectl top pods" via api

Answer (score 0):

The answer is the same for anything that kubectl does: add `--v=10` and it'll show you in gory detail what it does

```
$ kubectl --v=10 -n kube-system get pods
...
curl -v -XGET https://awesome-k8s-api-server:443/apis/metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/namespaces/kube-system/pods
```